# Can I make a variable _const from now on_?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, constants

I'm using a library that has a class with an `init` function distinct from its constructor. Every time I make a new instance I need to call, for example:

```
MyClass a;
a.init();
```

Since `init` is not `const`, this prevents me from creating const instances (I can't write `const MyClass a`). Is there some way to call init and then declare from "here on out" (I guess for the remainder of the scope) my variable is `const`?

This works, but relies on not touching the original variable:

```
MyClass dont_touch;
dont_touch.init();
const MyClass & a = dont_touch;
```

Comment: The answer is no. Like you, I wish it was yes.

Comment: You can also use `const_cast` for the `init` call to do it quick and dirty. That is, declare the object `const`, and `const_cast` around the object for the `init` call. However, `const_cast` is generally considered bad practice, and I've gotta say I think the [templated solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23400028/3100771) is super slick.

Comment: @Apriori Definitely Undefined Behaviour.  Can't const_cast away const from an a defined const object and do non-const stuff to it.

Comment: @Andre Kostur: Thank you, good call, I never realized or forgot this was undefined behavior. On the plus side you can see how much I use const_cast. C++ gave me the gun...

Comment: You can cast away const if you have a const reference to an underlying object which is non-const .. but that is not the case in this example

Comment: @Matt McNabb: After some searching I've found some inconsistent information on casting away const. Would you agree it's also true you can cast away const from a const object so long as you don't modify it?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not sure what the status is of calling a non-const member function on such an object

Comment: By the way, `init()` work should be done in constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using C++11 you could use a lambda function

```
const MyClass ConstantVal = []{ 
    MyClass a;
    a.init(); 
    return a; 
}();
```

This allows you to keep the initialization in place while never giving outside access to the mutable object.
see also:
http://herbsutter.com/2013/04/05/complex-initialization-for-a-const-variable/

Comment: I think this is more optimizable than my solution also, since the compiler can then assume that the object is never modified.

Comment: This answers my specific question. Though I could have asked a more general question where `a.init()` is replaced with some arbitrary operation that might not reasonably fit in the lambda.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a wrapper class and use that instead.

If MyClass has a virtual destructor you can feel safe deriving from it like this:

```
class WrapperClass : public MyClass 
{
public:
    WrapperClass()
    {
        init(); // Let's hope this function doesn't throw
    }
};
```

Or write a class that contains the MyClass instance

```
class WrapperClass
{
public:
    WrapperClass()
    {
        m_myClass.init(); // Let's hope this function doesn't throw
    }
    operator MyClass&() {return m_myClass;}
    operator const MyClass&() const {return m_myClass;}
private:
    MyClass m_myClass;
};
```

Or write a template to solve this general problem using one of the two solutions above: eg.

```
template <class T> class WrapperClass : public T
{
public:
    WrapperClass()
    {
        T::init();
    }
};

typedef WrapperClass<MyClass> WrapperClass;
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting such a derived class can be defined within and local to the function it's used if desired. But using the template solution is even better and sidesteps this, because you can just instantiate at will.

Comment: It's perfectly fine for `init` to throw. Let's hope it doesn't return an error code. The usual reason for `init` functions is that the developer knows an error can occur, but doesn't know exceptions, so he can't report the error if it happens in the ctor.

Answer (score 5):

Create a function that wraps the first two lines and gives you an object that is ready to go.

```
MyClass makeMyClass()
{
   MyClass a;
   a.init();
   return a;
}

// Now you can construct a const object or non-const object.
const MyClass a = makeMyClass();
MyClass b = makeMyClass();
```

**Update**

Using `makeMyClass()` involves construction and destruction of a temporary object everytime the function is called. If that becomes a significant cost, `makeMyClass()` can be altered to:

```
MyClass const& makeMyClass()
{
   static bool inited = false;
   static MyClass a;
   if ( !inited )
   {
     inited = true;
     a.init();
   }
   return a;
}
```

It's usage, as described earlier, will continue to work. In addition, once can also do this:

```
const MyClass& c = makeMyClass();
```

Comment: Yes, it does come at the cost of a copy.

Comment: @mangledorf I'm not sure about this, but [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) might be useful.  So if I understand it right, if you use `-O3`, I don't think you need to worry about this.  Just a thought.

Comment: Even if RVO is present you need to make sure that your class's copy-constructor is correct.

Comment: `const MyClass a = makeMyClass();` may be also `const MyClass& a = makeMyClass();`.

Comment: If the class is move enabled (using c++11) then it is guaranteed not to make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it quite simply, even without C++11 and lambdas:

```
const MyClass a;
{
    MyClass _a;
    _a.init();
    std::swap(const_cast<MyClass&>(a), _a);
}
```

The use of `const_cast` is admittedly a bit of a hack, but it won't break anything as `const` is quite a weak specifier. At the same time, it is quite efficient, as the `MyClass` object is only swapped, not copied (most reasonable expensive-to-copy objects should provide a `swap` function and inject an overload of `std::swap`).

Without the cast, it would require a helper:

```
struct Construct_Init {
    operator MyClass() const
    {
        MyClass a;
        a.init();
        return a;
    }
};
const MyClass a = Construct_Init();
```

This can be like this in a function (the `Construct_Init` structure needs not be declared at namespace scope), but it is a bit longer. The copy of the object may or may not be optimized away using copy elision.

Note that in both cases, the return value of `init()` is lost. If it returns a boolean where `true` is success and `false` is failure, it is better to:

```
if(!a.init())
    throw std::runtime_error("MyClass init failed");
```

Or just make sure to handle the errors appropriately.